# Node Azure function works locally, but not in Azure

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions

I am working on a Node Azure Function (on Linux) to create a GIF image on the fly.   It all works wonderfully on my local MacBook, but fails when I deploy to Azure.

When peaking into the Logs, I just see it throws a `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException` in logs when deployed to Azure.

Below is my in-progress code.   I have included the full function code as there is no obvious (to me) indication of the error source.  Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing this issue?

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
import { DateTime, Duration } from "luxon";
import { Canvas } from "canvas";
import * as fs from 'fs'; 

const os = require('os');
const { GifEncoder } = require("@skyra/gifenc")
const { buffer } = require('node:stream/consumers');

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    
    try {
        let countdownTo: string = req.query.countdownTo || DateTime.now().plus({days: 7}).toFormat("yyyy-LL-dd'T'T");
        let width: number = parseInt(req.query.width) || 300;
        let height: number = parseInt(req.query.height);
        let frames: number = parseInt(req.query.frames) || 180;
        let background: string = '#' + (req.query.background || '000e4e');
        let foreground: string = '#' + (req.query.foreground || '00b7f1');

        // Set height to 1/3 width if not specified
        if (!height) {
            height = width/3;
        }
        
        // ========================================================================

        // Set upper and lower limits 
        width = Math.max(width, Math.min(120, 640));
        height = Math.max(height, Math.min(120, 640));
        frames = Math.max(frames, Math.min(1, 600));
        
        // Time calculations
        const nowDate: DateTime = DateTime.now()
        const targetDate: DateTime = DateTime.fromISO(countdownTo); // "2022-11-01T12:00"
        let timeDifference: Duration = targetDate.diff(nowDate);

        // ========================================================================

        const encoder: any = new GifEncoder(width, height);
        const canvas: Canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
        const ctx: any = canvas.getContext('2d');

        let fileName = targetDate.toFormat('yyyyLLddHHmmss') + '-' + nowDate.toFormat('yyyyLLddHHmmss') + '.gif';
        // Specify temporary directory and create if it doesn't exist
        const temporaryFileDirectory: string = os.tmpdir() + '/tmp/';
        if (!fs.existsSync(temporaryFileDirectory)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(temporaryFileDirectory);
        }

        // Stream the GIF data into a file
        let filePath: string = temporaryFileDirectory + fileName + '.gif';
        const readStream = encoder.createReadStream()
        readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
        
        // Set the font size, style, and alignment
        let fontSize: string = Math.floor(width/12) + 'px';
        let fontFamily: string = 'Arial';
        ctx.font = [fontSize, fontFamily].join(' ');
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

        // Start Encoding GIF
        encoder.setRepeat(0).setDelay(1000).setQuality(10).start();
        
        if (timeDifference.milliseconds <= 0) { // Date has passed
            context.log('EXPIRED Date:', countdownTo);
            
            // Set Canvas background color
            ctx.fillStyle = background;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            // Print Text
            ctx.fillStyle = foreground;
            ctx.fillText('Date has passed!', (width/2), (height/2));

            // Add frame to the GIF
            encoder.addFrame(ctx);
        }
        else {  // Date is in the future
            
            timeDifference = targetDate.diff(DateTime.now(), ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']);
            context.log('Date:', countdownTo);

            for (let i: number = 0; i < frames; i++) {
                
                // Extract the duration from the days
                let days: number = Math.floor(timeDifference.days);
                let hours: number = Math.floor(timeDifference.hours);
                let minutes: number = Math.floor(timeDifference.minutes);
                let seconds: number = Math.floor(timeDifference.seconds);

                let daysDisplay: any = (days.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + days : days;
                let hoursDisplay: any = (hours.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + hours : hours;
                let minutesDisplay: any = (minutes.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
                let secondsDisplay: any = (seconds.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

                // Create the text to be displayed
                let displayText: string = [daysDisplay, 'd ', hoursDisplay, 'h ', minutesDisplay, 'm ', secondsDisplay, 's'].join('');
                //context.log(displayText);

                // Set Canvas background color
                ctx.fillStyle = background;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

                // Print Text
                ctx.fillStyle = foreground;
                ctx.fillText(displayText, (width/2), (height/2));

                // Add frame to the GIF
                encoder.addFrame(ctx);

                // Remove a second in preparation for the next frame
                if (seconds < 1) {
                    if (minutes < 1) {
                        if (hours < 1) {
                            timeDifference = timeDifference.minus({days: 1});
                        }
                        timeDifference = timeDifference.minus({hours: 1});
                    }
                    timeDifference = timeDifference.minus({minutes: 1});
                    timeDifference = timeDifference.plus({seconds: 59});
                }
                else {
                    timeDifference = timeDifference.minus({seconds: 1});
                }
                
            }
        }

        
        // Encoding complete...
        encoder.finish();

        const fileData = await buffer(readStream);
        //context.log(fileData);
        context.res = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "image/gif"
            },
            isRaw: true,
            status: 200,
            body: new Uint8Array(fileData)
        };
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
    }
    catch(ex: any) {
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: ex.message
        };
    }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this issue was related to an issue with Azure DevOps pipeline.   The pipeline indicated that it had ran successfully, but it never installed any node_modules.

The node_modules folder on the Function App was empty after deployment, causing references to things like Luxon to fail completely.

I switched to Github Actions and it worked fine, so apparently some step was incorrect in the pipeline.

If you run into an issue with a particular function working perfectly locally, but not in production -- double check to ensure that your CI/CD pipelines are working successfully.